# Нужно получить результат выполнения sql запроса

Tags: sql, qt, qtcreator

```
querygr.prepare("select GroupID from Group_medicines where trim(Group_medicines.name) = trim(Group)");
```

вот такой запрос. нужно вытянуть результат(так будет одно число всего лишь) его нужно присвоить переменной типа `int`. Пишу в QT.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Выполняем запрос prepare
if( querygr.exec() ) {
    // Получаем возвращаемые значения в виде итерируемого списка
    while (query.next()) {
        int groupId = query.value(0).toInt();
        doSomething(groupId);
    }
} else {
    qDebug() << querygr.lastError().text();
}
```

Comment: Не работает... возможно что-то с запросом не так? у меня в таблице груп_медицинс есть поле нейм, а вот поле груп достается и комбобокса...может что-то можете предложить для исправления?Благодарю за первый ответ.

Comment: @Kotinho покажите ошибку (добавил в ответ как это сделать)

Comment: Спасибо, уже решил данную проблемы